# use of "納めはしても" in this statement

Tags: reading-comprehension

> まず鬼の『自分のすぐ近くに誰かが隠れているはずがない』
>
> という先入観を利用し、鬼は無意識にひまりを視界の中**に納めはしても**、それ以上の索敵はしなくなる

a discussion on hide and seek strategy; hiding close to where the the seeker is counting, which is what himari is doing. speaker is an observer, neither himari or the seeker

> (after the seeker opens their eyes when the countdown ends), at first they'd think "there can't be anyone> hiding close to me"
>
> The seeker has this preconception and even though, unconsciously, within their
> field of view, the seeker does ____ to himari,  beyond that the seeker will stop
> searching for (himari) (to look for the other "hiders").

i can't figure out what 納めはして is suppose to be as "____"

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(AをBに)[おさめる](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%8F%8E%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B) has multiple meanings, but in this case it just means "to put A into B". 視界におさめる is a [set phrase](http://yourei.jp/%E8%A6%96%E7%95%8C%E3%81%AB%E5%8F%8E%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B). (As for kanji, I think 視界に収める is more common.)

So ひまりを視界の中におさめる means "to put Himari in the seeker's field of view" or "to have Himari in the seeker's sight". This usually means looking at her intentionally, but in this case it clearly means seeing her without noticing her.